# Get a user's email address from the username via PowerShell and WMI?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi, powershell-2.0

I have a user's network login name.  From PowerShell and WMI is it possible to get a valid email for that user?  Note that the login name is different than the name in the email, so I can't just combine the login name with the email domain.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**The simplest way is to useActive-Directory.**

As you are using PowerShell tag and not PowerShell V2.0 you can use ADSI.

```
Clear-Host
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr","jpb@dom.fr","Pwd")

# Look for a user
$user2Find = "user1"
$Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$rc = $Rech.filter = "((sAMAccountName=$user2Find))"
$rc = $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
$rc = $Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

$theUser = $Rech.FindOne()
if ($theUser -ne $null)
{
  Write-Host $theUser.Properties["mail"]
}
```

You can also use `userPrincipalName` instead of `sAMAccountName` in the filter, for `userPrincipalName` you can use *user@domain* form.

---

**Using WMI** : If you absolutly want to do it with WMI.

```
$user2Find = "user1"
$query = "SELECT * FROM ds_user where ds_sAMAccountName='$user2find'"
$user = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -Namespace "root\Directory\LDAP"
$user.DS_mail
```

You can use the second solution localy on your server or from a computer inside the domain, but it's a bit more complicated to authenticate to WMI from outside the domain.

---

**Using PowerShell 2.0**

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$user2Find = "user1"
$user = Get-ADUser $user2Find -Properties mail
$user.mail
```

Comment: Wow, what a complete answer!  Thanks! The WMI version works for me.  I'll also give the 2.0 version a try.

Answer (score 15):

Here's another possible way ([original source](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/11/14/pstip-how-to-get-the-email-address-of-the-currently-logged-on-user/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20PowershellMagazine%20%28PowerShell%20Magazine%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)):

```
PS> [adsisearcher].FullName
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher

PS> $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(objectClass=user)"
PS> $searcher

CacheResults             : True
ClientTimeout            : -00:00:01
PropertyNamesOnly        : False
Filter                   : (objectClass=user)
PageSize                 : 0
PropertiesToLoad         : {}
ReferralChasing          : External
SearchScope              : Subtree
ServerPageTimeLimit      : -00:00:01
ServerTimeLimit          : -00:00:01
SizeLimit                : 0
SearchRoot               :
Sort                     : System.DirectoryServices.SortOption
Asynchronous             : False
Tombstone                : False
AttributeScopeQuery      :
DerefAlias               : Never
SecurityMasks            : None
ExtendedDN               : None
DirectorySynchronization :
VirtualListView          :
Site                     :
Container                :

PS> $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$env:USERNAME)"
PS> $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail
```

Comment: I needed just the two last lines in this answer for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not WMI, but this may do the job just as well:

```
PS> ([adsi]"WinNT://$env:USERDOMAIN/$env:USERNAME,user").Properties["mail"]
```