# Get primary Exchange account mail address from registry

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, registry, exchange-server

I have MS Exchange account as my primary mail account in my default mail profile. I need to get its mail address programmatically in some VBScript.

I've got Outlook installed, so I can do it like this:

```
MsgBox CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")
```

But only when Outlook is running, also I've got security prompts in Outlook, so I can't use this approach.

I've found that a bunch of information about profiles and accounts is stored in registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\`
I've found `Email` value for POP3 and IMAP accounts in subkeys of `9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676` in default profile, but none of that for Exchange account.

Where can find a value for Exchange account mail address of current user in registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't like the idea of using Redemption for that case. Its not free and requires additional movements to use. Anyway, I found an answer to my original question.

To get user primary SMTP address of the Outlook Exchage account on the end-user computer you need to search registry down the key of default mail profile (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\<default profile name>` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\<default profile name>` for older versions of Outlook) for the value named `001f6641`. This value data has binary format and contains mail address in the form like this `SMPT:john@example.com`, just cut the `SMTP:` part out an you get mail address.

The bad part that you can't make it with Outlook 2003. For that case you can search registry the same way for the value named `001e660b` that contains `legacyExchangeDN`. Then you make an LDAP query (probably to Exchange AD by default) to find person with that `legacyExchangeDN`. What you need is `proxyAddresses` field. It has multiple values and that one that starts with `SMTP:` (uppercase is important), contains primary SMTP address.

Answer (score 2):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184052/get-a-users-email-address-from-the-username-via-powershell-and-wmi)The name of your default profile is stored in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\DefaultProfile
```

Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) (RDO) in stead of the standard Microsoft tools
(CDO), you'l have better tools and no security prompts.

> RDOSession.Logon method, which takes several parameters, including the
>   MAPI profile name (pass an empty string to use the default MAPI
>   profile)

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.Logon
set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
for each Msg in Inbox.Items
  Debug.Print(Msg.Subject)
next
```

Another option is to use ADSI and do an LDAP query.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184052/get-a-users-email-address-from-the-username-via-powershell-and-wmi).
Also see [this](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2003/monitoring-operations/Scripting-Exchange-VBScript-ADSI-Part2.html).

```
Set MyUser = GetObject ("LDAP://CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sunnydale,DC=muni")
For each email in MyUser.proxyAddresses
       WScript.Echo email
Next
```

Comment: Installing third-party software is not an option for me. This script will work on several machines. All I have is Outlook and VBScript.

Comment: it doesn't realy have to be installed, regsvr32 a dll will do, otherwise if you want to use MAPI you will have to take take the prompts iaa, i added something to the answer that also could help you

Comment: Redemption can also be used in C#/VB.Net/C++/Delphi without installing it in the registry using RedemptionLoader - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader.

Comment: If Outlook is already running you can set RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT to reuse Outlook's session.

Comment: To retrieve the current user's address, use RDOSession.CurrentUser.Address or RDOSession.CurrentUser.SMTPAddress .